# IE 10-11 flex-basis property behaves differently than webkit browsers

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox

I'm trying to use the [Media object](http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/media-object/), consisting of a `Media-body` and a `Media-figure`. The HTML and classes follow this form (order shouldn't matter).

```
.Media
   .Media-figure
   .Media-body
```

The simple CSS is (no prefixes):

```
.Media { 
   display: flex 
}

.Media-figure {
   flex: 0 0 auto;

   /* same as...
   flex-grow: 0;
   flex-shrink: 0;
   flex-basis: auto;
   */
}

.Media-body {
   flex: 1 1 0;

   /* same as...
   flex-grow: 1;
   flex-shrink: 1;
   flex-basis: 0;
   */
}
```

Notice that I'm tweaking the `Media-figure` flex-shrink factor to be 0 (as opposed to the link I posted). I'm assuming that the `Media-figure` is some fixed size, and we'd rather not make it smaller if we have too little room.

Using `flex-basis: 0` for the `Media-body` should set the element to have no initial size, which then allows it to consume the rest of the available space since it is the only element with `flex-grow: 1`. However, in IE10-11, the `flex-basis: 0` causes the `Media-body` width to be that of the interior elements, and destroys any wrapping behavior if there is too much content.

http://jsfiddle.net/sgardn04/3enpp4wg/

(Note: if you view these in chrome, they'll look exactly the same. **Use IE10-11!**)

My current workaround is to set the `Media-body { flex-basis: auto }`, which seems to work. I make the assumption that IE is at fault here, since I like the behavior of the webkit browsers better. Is there a legitimate interpretation of the spec that supports IEs rendering? Or any case where we could expect different behavior for webkit browsers based on the classes I have defined here? The two properties seem to behave exactly the same in this case.

EDIT: I found this [handy graphic](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/images/rel-vs-abs-flex.svg), which seems to suggest that the `flex-basis` property determines whether the space is distributed before or after the width of the elements is taken into account (`flex-basis: 0` vs `flex-basis: auto`).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The difference is due to not having a unit on the value of `flex-basis`. Adding this (or omitting the 0) gives you the expected behaviour in IE: [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3enpp4wg/8/)

The MDN documentation on `flex` mentions this:

> A preferred size of 0 **must** have a unit
>   to avoid being interpreted as a flexibility. Defaults to 0% when
>   omitted.

Comment: I've been reading through the documentation and have come to the same conclusion. Microsoft refer to "Width as specified by a number, **followed by a length unit**." in their MSDN documentation, and MDN state "Defined as a number **followed by a absolute unit** such as px, mm or pt, or a percentage of the parent flex container main size property"

Comment: MSDN also state for the flex property "You need to specify a zero flex-basis component with a unit or precede it by two flex factors to avoid misinterpretation or invalid declarations." - although with the flex-grow and flex-shrink the original code should be valid based on that statement. The specification concurs with MSDN and states "A unitless zero that is not already preceded by two flex factors must be interpreted as a flex factor. To avoid misinterpretation or invalid declarations, authors must specify a zero ‘flex-basis’ component with a unit or precede it by two flex factors."