# How to make flex-basis work in IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

My website is completely broken in IE11. The problem comes from `flex: 1 1 0%;`, which I use everywhere thanks to [autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) and [postcss-flexbugs-fixes](https://github.com/luisrudge/postcss-flexbugs-fixes).

The site does work on IE when I change it to `flex: 1 1 auto;`, but then some behaviors change (e.g. one flexbox with two `flex: 1 1 auto;` children which do not take exactly the same space). Therefore this solution breaks my designs on other browsers (while making it a lot nicer - not broken - on IE11).

How do people manage to make their sites built with Flexbox work on IE11?

Edit: here is a pen which highlights the problem I am facing: https://codepen.io/Zephir77167/pen/GMjBrd (try it on Chrome and IE11).

Edit2: here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div id="a" class="flex">
  <div id="b" class="item flex-1">
    Hey
  </div>
  <div id="c" class="item flex-0">
    Ho
  </div>
  <div id="d" class="item flex-1">
    Heyheyheyheyho
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<div id="a" class="flex">
  <div id="b" class="item flex-1-variation">
    Hey
  </div>
  <div id="c" class="item flex-0">
    Ho
  </div>
  <div id="d" class="item flex-1-variation">
    Heyheyheyheyho
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#a {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100px;
}

#b {
  background-color: green;
  height: 50px;
}

#c {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
}

#d {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 150px;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item.flex-0 {
  flex: none;
}

.item.flex-1 {
  flex: 1 1 0%;
}

.item.flex-1-variation {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

Comment: "IE 11 requires a unit to be added to the third argument, the flex-basis property" - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn254946%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: You can detect if the browser is IE11 and adjust CSS properties on that basis

Comment: `@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active),
(-ms-high-contrast: none) {
  .foo {
    /*IE styles go here */
  }
}`

Comment: Remove the percent sign `flex: 1 1 0`

Comment: See the third bullet point in the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32239549/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B Since I can't see _only one solution_ but a trial and error based on how the markup looks like, I think that answer/question suit great as a dupe

Comment: @LGSon, could be. Just posted as a comment so OP can review.

Comment: I would agree, certainly so long as we don't have a demo of OP's code to show otherwise. Better to close as a likely-helpful dupe than to close as lacking an MCVE.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28117862/ie-10-11-flex-basis-property-behaves-differently-than-webkit-browsers
hope it helps

Comment: @Paulie_D I have a unit, 0%. I also tried 0px, doesn't change anything.

Comment: @LGSon Just tried, doesn't work (IE doesn't recognize the flex property if the third argument has no unit)

Comment: @Michael_B I tried the 3 solutions, and still all produce the same output as 0%

Comment: Sorry everyone, I should have included a pen. Here is one which highlights my issue: https://codepen.io/Zephir77167/pen/GMjBrd You will notice the difference between, say, Chrome, and IE11.

Comment: @Zephir77167 Please include your code in the question itself, rather than linking to an external code sandbox like CodePen. It helps prevent link-rot if/when CodePen goes down and is also a requirement of the site for code-debugging questions.

Comment: Nevermind, I included it in the question. Sorry about that.

Comment: You can add `-ms-flex:1 1 auto;` after your standard rule to override it for IE.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Thanks but IE11 doesn't used prefixed properties (in inspector, `-ms-flex` is crossed, but not `flex`)

Comment: @Zephir77167 Actually IE11 supports and will use the `-ms-flex` if it comes after the standard `flex` property. The problem most likely come from the autoprefixer and postcss-flexbugs-fixes and where they place their code. It is highly likely that their code is added even further down and so it will override the previously manually set `-ms-flex`. See https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZXBrbx

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Indeed, you are very right. Could you post this as the answer so I can select it? Thanks!

Comment: see @LGSon's answer below. It has a cleaner approach to providing IE specific rules.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When it comes to IE11, you could target it explicit using this CSS rule:

```
_:-ms-fullscreen, :root .IE11-only-class { 

  /* IE11 specific properties */

}
```

Stack snippet

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#a {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100px;
}

#b {
  background-color: green;
  height: 50px;
}

#c {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
}

#d {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 150px;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item.flex-0 {
  flex: none;
}

.item.flex-1 {
  flex: 1 1 0%;
}

_:-ms-fullscreen, :root .IE-FlexAuto {
  flex-basis: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="a" class="flex">
  <div id="b" class="item flex-1 IE-FlexAuto">
    Hey
  </div>
  <div id="c" class="item flex-0">
    Ho
  </div>
  <div id="d" class="item flex-1 IE-FlexAuto">
    Heyheyheyheyho
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a post with an answer of mine, which talks some more about this, and also provide some script solutions which might be helpful

- [Instead of using prefixes I want to ask site visitors to upgrade their browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33359157/instead-of-using-prefixes-i-want-to-ask-site-visitors-to-upgrade-their-browser)

Answer (score 3):

I had a massive headache over this, rather than do a hack, set your flex-basis to auto, then if you have a container size, set the with to the same size, ie:

```
@include breakpoint(m){
  flex: 0 48%;
  flex-basis: auto;
  width: 48%;
}
```